# Cosine similarity between words using BERT model

Tags: python, data-analysis, bert-language-model, cosine-similarity

I have a simple script where I want to check the similarity between words "Cat" and "Dog"

```
from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer
import torch
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

# Load pre-trained BERT model and tokenizer
model_name = "bert-base-multilingual-cased"
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

tokens_cat = tokenizer("Cat", return_tensors="pt")
tokens_dog = tokenizer("Dog", return_tensors="pt")

# Get BERT embeddings
with torch.no_grad():
    embeddings_cat = model(**tokens_cat).last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1).squeeze().numpy()
    embeddings_dog = model(**tokens_dog).last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1).squeeze().numpy()

# Calculate cosine similarity
cosine_similarity = 1 - cosine(embeddings_cat, embeddings_dog)

print(f"Cosine Similarity: {cosine_similarity}")
```

The code above returns 0.8319976329803467, which is weird because these words are not similar. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I tried to ask chatGPT and it keeps telling me that this code is right.

Comment: The embeddings of these two words are based on the context in which these two words had in their training data. Therefore, your code is correct and the high cosine similarity score simply shows that these two words move towards the same direction (i.e., appear in the same context). As far as I know, this applies for the embeddings generated by BERT. If you want more word-focused embeddings consider using GloVe or Word2Vec.
Check: https://mccormickml.com/2019/05/14/BERT-word-embeddings-tutorial/